# What character encoding is c3 82 c2 bf?

Tags: unicode, encoding

I have a source of text data that includes the byte sequence c3 82 c2 bf. In context I think it's supposed to be a capital Greek Phi symbol (Φ).

Anyway I can't figure out what encoding is being used; I'm writing a Python script to process this data into a database that expects Unicode, and it throws an exception on this particular sequence of data.

Any suggestions on how to handle it?

Comment: Can you post more sample data encoded with the magic encoding? What makes you think it is a single letter?

Comment: In context it's "magnetic flux \xc3\x82\xc2\xbf<sub>fa<sub>" which should probably be &Phi;<sub>fa</sub>

Comment: That's the only failure data so far, so I only have that to go on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Interpreted as UTF-8, c3 82 is “Â” U+00C2 and c2 bf is “¿” U+00BF, which does not make much sense, but it’s technically valid UTF-8 data, so it should not be reported as character-level data error. Interpreted as UTF-16, it’s Hangul syllables and possibly a CJK ideograph, depending on endianness, but still formally valid data, though most probably not what was meant.

This sounds like the result of double conversion, but it’s difficult to make educated guesses. If it stands for Φ, then the UTF-16 form is 03 A6 or A6 03 and the UTF-8 form is CE A6, which don’t really resemble the actual data. Information about the origin of the data might help in guessing what transcodings may have happened.

Comment: It looks like a double-encoded U+00BF, INVERTED QUESTION MARK.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, that’s right! If you have U+00BF and you UTF-8 encode it, you get the bytes C2 BF. If you mistakenly interpret these bytes as U+00C2 and U+00BF and UTF-8 encode them, you get C3 82 C2 BF, as in the actual data.

Comment: It remains a problem where “¿” comes from. I would normally expect it to be the result of yet another wrong conversion (presumable between to 8-bit encodings), but I can’t imagine what it might be.

Comment: https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html#bf doesn't have Φ anywhere but there are a couple of other half-promising Greek glyphs there.

Comment: Here's a PowerShell script that may help someone to determine what is inner encoding within double encoded utf8 string is. For this particular character ¿, candidates are `iso-8859-15`, `iso-8859-9`, `iso-8859-1`, `windows-1258`, `windows-1254`, `Windows-1252`: `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncodings() | % {"$($_.CodePage) $($_.Name): " + [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($_.CodePage).GetBytes([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString((0xC3, 0x82, 0xC2, 0xBF))) ) }`

Answer (score 11):

It's probably a double conversion from `Ñ` character.

`Ñ` character in **UTF-8** is: `0xc391`.

If you try to convert from **LATIN-1** to **UTF-8** the `Ñ` character which is already encoded in **UTF-8**, you'll get: `0xc382c2bf`.

Why?

1. `0xc382` is **UTF-8** translation from **LATIN-1** `0xc3` character `Ã` (A with tilde)
2. `0xc2bf` is `¿` character which is what you get when you can't convert a character from **LATIN-1** (`0x91` is an invalid character in **LATIN-1**

Comment: Thanks but nothing to do with Ñ , this is an engineering paper where &Phi; makes sense.

Comment: Most likely, that `(A with tilde) + (upside ?)` is the result of _any_ inadvertent double conversion.  As such, there would be no way to reverse your way back to the original character.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I ended up with `c3 82 c2 bf` from `&nbsp;`. I did not dig into the transformations because I was able to simply throw that part of the code away. Suffice it to say that `&nbsp;` was in an html email template that was processed by a wordpress (php) plugin.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893983/prevent-beautifulsoups-rendercontents-from-changing-nbsp-to-%c3%82 though the mystery sequence is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason. But maybe there is a possible scenary.

binary x0xx is converted to 0xC2 x0xx

binary x1xx is converted to 0xC3 x0xx

So there are lots of c2 and c3 added.

Where does this happen? Send non ascii in url query string for an ajax call, the Flask server will do this.

Answer (score -1):

i have received this character \xc3\x82 from external utf-16 document after conversion to utf-8 using $str = mb_convert_encoding($content, "UTF-8" , "UTF-16LE"); (PHP)

original sequence was 0xA0 0x00 and the converter converted it probably to what it meant to be NBSP .. it was character at thousands separator in currency number. nbsp is \xc2\xa0 so right now i have thousands removal as:

```
$price = str_replace(["\xc2\xa0","\xc3\x82"], '', $price);
```

Comment: thanks but this was an engineering paper, nothing to do with currency.