# What is Â¿ in Text Files

Tags: c#, encoding, character

I am working on a C# program which processes a bunch of text files.  These files have been created by a system so I can't change the source, but within the file Â¿ appears multiple times which is causing my code to fall over.

What does Â¿ mean and how can I handle it?

Comment: Have you tried using UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1 as the encoding for those files?

Comment: @NullUserException - Do you mean when reading the file?

Comment: You should find out what the encoding of those files you are getting actually is and process them as such. Letting things default is never a good idea.

Comment: @hshah Yes. [​](http://google.com)

Comment: Related (emphasis mine): [What character encoding is c3 82 **c2 bf**?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11546351/50776)

Comment: @NullUserException - As UTF-8 I just see the ¿

Comment: So this is a bunch of Spanish text?

Comment: @Hans - No, it is English and I only see the upside down question mark in certain places.

Comment: Well, if you cannot describe the proper format of the file then post it on a file sharing service so somebody else can take a look at it.  Don't discount the possibility that a bug is located in the program that generated the file btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Â¿ means you have a character that is converted from another encoding type and is not recognized in the character table of your encoding type. You may handle it if you use another encoding type.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

Comment: The members of `System.Text.Encoding` are *not* enum items.

Comment: I still don’t think that will work (at least, not reliably) – encoding autodetection only works after you’ve actually read anything. On the plus side, you rarely need to check the encoding afterwards (why would you?), you just read the file.

Comment: @Konrad: No, finally and after many changes this will work :)
When you read a file in the same encoding as it was written you´ll get no character table errors like "Â¿"

Comment: @Paedow The `if (…)` test won’t work (*and* is unnecessary). [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding.aspx) explicitly says “encoding autodetection is not done until the first call to a Read method”. Also, you cannot do `new sr.CurrentEncoding()`, that isn’t even valid syntax.

Answer (score 3):

At the start of Unicode-encoded files is a "header".  This header tells programs reading it that it's a Unicode file.  This is called a "Byte order mark" and signifies to readers what type of Unicode it is.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374101(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, first you should find out what encoding was used when these were created, then use that encoding when reading them in. Check out:

```
BinaryReader(Stream, Encoding)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx