# What is the encoding of e6 b5 8b e8 af 95

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding

I have a source of text data that includes the byte sequence `e6 b5 8b e8 af 95`. In the context I believe it should be the Chinese character "测试".

My perl source code is supposed to pick up this byte sequence (unfortunately this is not in UTF-8 and I cannot encode it to UTF-8 and decode back), but under some circumstances the sequence becomes `c3 a6 c2 b5 c2 8b c3 a8 c2 af c2 95`.

Trying to figure out the likely reasons why `c3` and `c2` are added. Is it the problem of double conversion mentioned in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546351/what-character-encoding-is-c3-82-c2-bf)?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I can verify that the byte sequence is 测试. And the second byte sequence gives garbage when decoded as UTF-8. What's your code like? Where is this byte sequence coming from?

Comment: Use `Encode::decode('utf8', $data)` to convert the byte sequence into an Unicode string.

Comment: @piojo the byte sequence is from the output of a program I'm using as input. Most of the time it goes through well (I am receiving `e6 b5 8b e8 af 95`), but sometimes if an earlier input is decoded to UTF-8, this input will become incorrect (`c3 a6 c2 b5 c2 8b c3 a8 c2 af c2 95`)

Comment: @salva you mean, to use `Encode::decode('utf8', $data)` for `c3 a6 c2 b5 c2 8b c3 a8 c2 af c2 95` ? Both `c3 a6 c2 b5 c2 8b c3 a8 c2 af c2 95` and `e6 b5 8b e8 af 95` are not in UTF-8.

Comment: @SinanÜnür I am reading and printing the output from/to shell script. The input `e6 b5 8b e8 af 95` is from an output of a C++ program and will be processed by my perl program.

Comment: I think @JiajuShen is trying to figure out what's going on with someone else's program, not his own. The c++ program is a black box, no? You can't read the code and see what it's doing?

Comment: @JiajuShen Yes, you're right. It's being double-encoded.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Yes, that's my take on it. This isn't really a perl question.

Comment: @piojo thanks for the explanation, I think that might be exactly what's going on. But can I know why when I checked the encoding using is_utf8, it returns false? I would assume it should return true if the byte sequence is double encoded?

Comment: Never use `is_utf8`. It checks the how the string is stored internally, which is unimportant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`06d4b 08bd5` are the Unicode Code Points for `测试`.

`b5 8b e8 af 95` is the UTF-8 encoding of `测试`.

`c3 a6 c2 b5 c2 8b c3 a8 c2 af c2 95` is the UTF-8 encoding of the UTF-8 encoding of `测试`.

```
$ perl -e'
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use utf8;
    use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

    my $s = "测试";
    print "$s\n";
    printf "%v05X\n", $s;

    utf8::encode($s);
    printf "%v02X\n", $s;

    utf8::encode($s);
    printf "%v02X\n", $s;
'
测试
06D4B.08BD5
E6.B5.8B.E8.AF.95
C3.A6.C2.B5.C2.8B.C3.A8.C2.AF.C2.95
```

---

```
$ perl -MJSON -e'
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use utf8;
    use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

    my $s = "测试";
    printf "%1\$s (%1\$v05X)\n", $s;
    my $data = [ $s ];
    my $json_utf8 = JSON->new->utf8->encode($data);
    printf "%v02X\n", $json_utf8;
    $data = JSON->new->utf8->decode($json_utf8);
    $s = $data->[0];
    printf "%1\$s (%1\$v05X)\n", $s;
'
测试 (06D4B.08BD5)
5B.22.E6.B5.8B.E8.AF.95.22.5D
测试 (06D4B.08BD5)
```

Comment: Yes, and probably the OP's program is re-encoding the other programs already encoded output rather than decoding it.

Comment: Thank you. I think this might be a problem of the source code I am looking into. The only difference between `E6.B5.8B.E8.AF.95` and `C3.A6.C2.B5.C2.8B.C3.A8.C2.AF.C2.95` is that an earlier input is decoded from a UTF-8 string using `JSON->new->utf8->decode()`. Will the earlier input affect the later one in this case?

Comment: `JSON->new->utf8->decode()` expects UTF-8 (`E6.B5.8B.E8.AF.95`), and returns Unicode Code Points (`06D4B.08BD5`).

Comment: @ikegami but the input I decode using `JSON->new->utf8->decode()` is not `测试` but an earlier input. Using the same set of source code, if the input is all ascii, the `测试` will not be affected at all. Is it likely some environment settings is altered by using  `JSON->new->utf8->decode()` ?

Comment: Also @ikegami is there a library/approach to prevent double encoding? Thanks.

Comment: Re "*if the input is all ascii, the 测试 will not be affected at all.*", That sentence makes no sense; neither "测" nor "试" are found in ASCII.

Comment: Re "*is there a library/approach to prevent double encoding?*", Yeah, simply don't do it. Don't pass UTF-8 where UCP are expected.

Comment: Re "*Is it likely some environment settings is altered by using `JSON->new->utf8->decode()`*", No. It's not just not likely, it doesn't happen.

Comment: @ikegami if the earlier input (please note that the `JSON->new->utf8->decode()` is used for an earlier input ) is something like `test`, the `测试` will not be affected, but if the input is `日本`, the `测试` will be double converted. Is it likely that the decoding of earlier argument affects later?

Comment: None of that makes sense, and the comments are not the place to ask new questions. You're just repeating [your earlier unanswerable question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788793/589924). Please address the issues raised in the comments of that answer.

Comment: ...Specifically, please provide a minimal, runable demonstration of the problem.