# What is the best practice to preserve the code page(s) of content when decoding from a json string?

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, utf-8

This question is related to my previous questions:

[What is the encoding of b2 e2 ca d4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844321/what-is-the-encoding-of-b2-e2-ca-d4)

[What is the encoding of e6 b5 8b e8 af 95](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799683/what-is-the-encoding-of-e6-b5-8b-e8-af-95)

I am running into an issue while decoding a jsong string to a json object in perl. The json string has Chinese characters `测试`, which I believe is encoded in UTF-8 (with octal code `E6 B5 8B E8 AF 95`), and some other non-ascii characters that are not UTF-8 encoded (with octal code `b2 e2 ca d4`).

The task is to decode the json string to json object, perserving correct encoding. I found that by using `JSON->new->utf8->decode()` we are able to decode `测试` correctly (if the json string does not contain any non-utf-8 encoded content).

But the decoding returns an error if the json string contains the non-utf-8 encoded character `JSON parsing error: malformed UTF-8 character in JSON string, at character offset 255 (before "\x{a2294}\x{2294}","...") at...`.

This is expected, as the string (whose octal code is `b2 e2 ca d4`) is not utf-8 encoded. But if decoded using `JSON->new->decode()` the result is incorrect, as `测试` becomes something else, as I see the octal code becomes `C3 A6 C2 B5 C2 8B C3 A8 C2 AF C2 95` instead of the original `E6 B5 8B E8 AF 95`.

Can I know if there is a good practice in decoding json string that preserves the original encoding, if the string contain different encoding in its content?

Comment: Re "*But the decoding returns an error if the json string contains the non-utf-8 encoded character*", What else could you expect from an improperly-encoded document? You should fix whatever is incorrectly encoding the JSON.

Comment: @ikegami and make sure we use JSON->new->utf8->decode() ?

Comment: The general usage is: `JSON->new->decode(Encode::decode($encoding, $encoded_json))`, but you can use `JSON->new->utf8->decode($encoded_json)` if UTF-8 is the character encoding used (which is the normal case).

Comment: If that other data is some kind of binary data, perhaps you should pass is through `encode_base64`?

Comment: @ikegami for some reason that data is probably not encoded in utf-8 (I believe it is in ISO-8859) and we need to pass it correctly with the correct original encoding. How can we pass it through `base64`?

Comment: Re "*we need to pass it [...] with the [...] original encoding.*", That's a stupid thing to do. Having to deal with more than one encoding at a time is a whole lot of extra work, it's error prone, and it means you're working with encoded bytes instead of text, so you can't use anything that works on text (such as regular expressions and `$json->encode`). To convert bytes into text without removing the character decoding, you can use `encode_base64`: `use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 ); my $text = encode_base64($bytes, '');`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are trying to use JSON to transmit binary data, but it's not well suited for that. I would base64-encode the binary data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use utf8;

use Encode       qw( encode );
use JSON::XS     qw( encode_json );
use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );

binmode STDOUT;

my $mime_doc1 = encode('iso-latin-1', <<'__EOS__');
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-latin-1

Éric
__EOS__

my $mime_doc2 = encode('UTF-8', <<'__EOS__');
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

测试
__EOS__

my @encoded_docs = map { encode_base64($_, '') }
   $mime_doc1,
   $mime_doc2;

my $json_utf8 = encode_json({
   title => '♡',
   docs  => \@encoded_docs,
});

say $json_utf8;
```

Output (with whitespace added):

```
{
   "title": "♡",
   "docs": [
      "Q29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluOyBjaGFyc2V0PWlzby1sYXRpbi0xCgrJcmljCg==",
      "Q29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluOyBjaGFyc2V0PVVURi04CgrmtYvor5UK"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that if the input is already a mixture of characters of both encodings ('iso-latin-1' and 'UTF-8'), there is no good way for `encode_base64` to handle it?

Comment: That seems very odd that the `encode_base64` and `decode_base64` only work in my testing prog. I printed out the string that I encoded using `encode_base64`, and when I copy-and-pasted this to my own testing program using `decode_base64`, it is able to be decoded correctly. But my program still interprets the `测试` as a string with octal code `C3 A6 C2 B5 C2 8B C3 A8 C2 AF C2 95` instead of `E6 B5 8B E8 AF 95`, and the string that is encoded in iso-latin was still `c2 b2 c3 a2 c3 8a c3 94`, even after I used `encode_base64` and `decode_base64`.

Comment: Is that a question? Because you haven't showed either of those programs