# Prevent BeautifulSoup's renderContents() from changing &nbsp; to Â

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm using [bs4](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to do some work on some text, but in some cases it converts `&nbsp;` characters to `Â`.  The best I can tell is that this is an [encoding mismatch from UTF-8 to latin1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp) (or reverse?)

Everything in my web app is UTF-8, Python3 is UTF-8, and I've confirmed the database is UTF-8.

I've narrowed down the problem to this one line:

```
print("Before soup: " + text)  # Before soup: &nbsp;
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
#.... do stuff to soup, but all commented out for this testing.
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.renderContents(), "html.parser")  # <---- PROBLEM!
print(soup.renderContents())  # b'\xc3\x82\xc2\xa0'
print("After SOUP: " + str(soup))  # After SOUP: Â
```

How do I prevent renderContents() from changing the encoding?  There is [no documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=RenderContents&check_keywords=yes&area=default) on this function!

Edit: Upon further research into the docs, [this seems to be the key](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters), but I still can't fix the problem!

```
print(soup.prettify(formatter="html"))  # &Acirc;&nbsp;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25871885/874188 looks too similar to be pure coincidence,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, apparently I hadn't read deep enough in to the docs, here's where the answer can be found:

From https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings:

The problem is that the snippet of code provided to BS is so short, that BeautifulSoup's sub-library `Unicode, Dammit`, doesn't have enough info to properly guess the encoding.

> `Unicode, Dammit` guesses correctly most of the time, but sometimes it
>   makes mistakes. ...you can avoid
>   mistakes and delays by passing it to the BeautifulSoup constructor as
>   `from_encoding`.

So the key is to add `from_encoding="UTF-8"` to each time the BS is constructed:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.renderContents(), "html.parser", from_encoding="UTF-8")`