# Struggling with utf-16 encoding/decoding

Tags: python, utf-16

I'm parsing a document that have some UTF-16 encoded string.

I have a byte string that contains the following:

```
my_var = b'\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbf\x004\x004\x000\x003\x006\x006\x000\x006\x00-\x001\x000\x000\x003\x008\x000\x006\x002\x002\x008\x005'
```

When converting to utf-8, I get the following output:

```
print(my_var.decode('utf-8'))
#> þÿ44036606-10038062285
```

The first two chars **þÿ** indicate it's a BOM for UTF-16BE, [as indicated on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding)

But, what I don't understand is that if I try the UTF16 BOM like this:

```
if value.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE)
```

This returns false. In fact, printing `codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE` doesn't show the same results:

```
print(codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE)
#> b'\xfe\xff'
```

**Why is that?** I'm suspecting some enconding issues on the higher end but not sure how to fix that one.

There are already a few mentions of how to decode UTF-16 on Stackoverflow (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827419/converting-utf-16-utf-8-and-remove-bom)), and they all say one thing: Decode using `utf-16` and Python will handle the BOM.

... But that doesn't work for me.

```
print(my_var.decode('utf-16')
#> 뻃뿃㐀㐀　㌀㘀㘀　㘀ⴀ㄀　　㌀㠀　㘀㈀㈀㠀㔀
```

But with UTF-16BE:

```
print(my_var.decode('utf-16be')
#> 쎾쎿44036606-10038062285
```

(the bom is not removed)

And with UTF-16LE:

```
print(my_var.decode('utf-16le')
#> 뻃뿃㐀㐀　㌀㘀㘀　㘀ⴀ㄀　　㌀㠀　㘀㈀㈀㠀㔀
```

So, for a reason I can't explain, using only `.decode('UTF-16')` doesn't work for me. Why?

**UPDATE**

The original source string isn't the one I mentioned, but this one:

```
source = '\376\377\0004\0004\0000\0003\0006\0006\0000\0006\000-\0001\0000\0000\0003\0008\0000\0006\0002\0002\0008\0005'
```

I converted it using the following:

```
def decode_8bit(cls, match):
    value = match.group().replace(b'\\', b'')
    return chr(int(value, base=8)).encode('utf-8')

my_var = re.sub(b'\\\\[0-9]{1,3}', decode_8bit, source)
```

Maybe I did something wrong here?

Comment: The UTF-16 BOM is 0xFE 0xFF. Your input has something else. Probably related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546351/what-character-encoding-is-c3-82-c2-bf

Comment: The binary sequence you provided is not valid UTF-16. Checking the result of `print(...)` is not a valid way of checking encodings since `print` may not print some characters, so you shouldn't trust it.

Comment: @Tomalak, I've updated my question (at the end). I forgot to mention the original source, maybe it changes everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right that **þÿ** indicates the BOM for UTF-16BE, if you use the **[CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)** encoding.

The difference is the following:

Your first byte is 0x**C3**, which is 11000011 in binary.

- **UTF-8**:

The first two bits are set and indicate that your UTF-8 char is 2 byte long.
Getting **0xC3 0xBE** for your first character,  which is þ for UTF-8.

- **CP1252**

CP1252 is always 1 byte long and returns **Ã** for 0xC3.

But if you lookup 0xC3 in your linked BOM list you won't find any matching Encoding.
Looks like there wasn't a BOM in the first place.

<s>Using the default encoding is probably the way to go, which is [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes) for Windows.</s>

**Edit after original source added**

Your encoding to UTF-8 destorys the BOM because it is not valid UTF-8. Try to avoid decoding and pass on a list of bytes.

*OPs solution:*

```
bytes(int(value, base=8))
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added one more details to my question, explaining how I got the `my_var` value, maybe I did something wrong in there first?

Comment: @CyrilN. \376\377 is your BOM in base8. Your encoding to UTF-8 probably destorys it because it is not valid UTF-8. Try to avoid decoding and pass on a list of bytes or use a single byte encoding if there is no other way. A python expert might be more helpful with that.

Comment: Oh my, replacing `chr(int(value, base=8)).encode('utf-8')` by `bytes(int(value, base=8))` did the trick!

Comment: @CyrilN. Can you write that an answer, along with some reasoning what happened? I think this might be beneficial, since at least one other person here had the "c3 82 c2 bf" byte sequence and the thread over there was somewhat inconclusive.

Comment: @CyrilN. I added your solution to my answer. Let me know if you want to provide your own answer. In that case i will remove it ASAP. I would encourage you to do so if you know why it happend. I tried to look into the chr() and encode() function but couldnt explain why 0xFF 0xFE was converted to 0xC3 0x82 0xC2 0xBF.

Comment: I've answered it, but you can keep the accepted answer @Hyarus, you helped me go in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As per requested by @Tomalak and @Hyarus, here's the reason of my issue:

When decoding the 8bit values, I was returning them as UTF-8 encoded:

```
def decode_8bit(cls, match):
    value = match.group().replace(b'\\', b'')
    return chr(int(value, base=8)).encode('utf-8')

my_var = re.sub(b'\\\\[0-9]{1,3}', decode_8bit, source)
```

This was messing the data returned since it was not encoded using UTF-8 (duh). So the correct code should have been:

```
def decode_8bit(cls, match):
    value = match.group().replace(b'\\', b'')
    return bytes(int(value, base=8))

my_var = re.sub(b'\\\\[0-9]{1,3}', decode_8bit, source)
```

Hope that helps someone else... Good luck with encoding! :/

Comment: Do you know the exact cause? Does chr() not return 255? Or does encode() enforce UTF-8 at all costs and switches some bits?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't have a clue. I run my code on multiple and various sources, and everything worked, so it's good. But I don't know what caused the issue.